# Weak-* convergence and trace-class operators

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading a proof by Barry Simon, and he makes a statement equivalent to the following:

Let $X$ be the space of compact operators over a Hilbert space $H$. Let $\{y_n\}_n$, $y_n>0$, be a bounded sequence in the dual space $X'$ of trace-class operators over $H$. (In fact we have $1 \leq tr (y_n) \leq g < +\infty$.) By Banach-Alaoglu, there is a weak-* convergent subsequence $\{y_n'\}$, i.e., there exists $y\in X'$ such that for every $A\in X$, $tr(Ay_n')\rightarrow tr(Ay)$.

This is fine. Then he claims, and this I don't understand:
"Clearly, $y \geq 0$ and therefore $\liminf_n tr(y_n) \geq tr(y).$"

Why can one conclude $y \geq 0$ easily, and how does the liminf-inequality follow easily? What am I missing? It is unclear from the text whether he considers the weak-* convergent subsequence in the quoted statement.

When I attempt at making my own argument, it becomes much stronger and more involved:

Use the subsequence: Can one argue by setting $A = P_k$, a sequence of projectors, and consider $y_{kn} = P_k y_n$? We have $tr(y_n)=\lim_k tr(P_k y_n)$, so that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K^n_\epsilon$ such that for all $k>K^n_\epsilon$ and all $n$ sufficiently large,

$$ | tr(y) - tr(P_ky_n)| \leq |tr(y) - tr(y_n)| + |tr(y_n) - tr(P_ky_n)| < \epsilon $$

If this is correct, then $tr(y_n)\rightarrow tr(y) > 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $y\geq0$: as $y_n'\geq0$ for all $n$ by hypothesis, we get, for any $\xi\in H$, and if we denote by $P_\xi$ the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb{C}\xi$,
$$
\langle y\xi,\xi\rangle=\mbox{tr}(yP_\xi)=\lim\mbox{tr}(y_n'P_\xi)=\lim\mbox{tr}(P_\xi y_n'P_\xi)\geq0,
$$
the last equality following from $y_n'\geq0$ and $P_\xi$ selfadjoint (it's actually positive). So $y\geq0$.

**Edit:**

The assertion $\liminf_n\mbox{tr}(y_n')\geq\mbox{tr}(y)$ is a particular case of the lower semicontinuity of the trace in the weak-$*$ topology.

Indeed, for each finite rank projection $P$ the function $x\mapsto\mbox{tr}(xP)$ is weak-$*$ continuous. And, moreover, if we fix an orthonormal basis $\{\xi_n\}$ and let $P_k=\sum_1^kP_{\xi_n}$, then 
$$
\mbox{tr}(x)=\sup_k\mbox{tr}(xP_k),\ \ \ \ \ \ x\in X'.
$$
This shows that in our situation the trace is a supremum of continuous functions, and thus lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Thanks! $y\geq 0$ was easy, I see that now ... But there is something I don't get about your discussion of the second fact: Here, you actually prove that $tr(y) \geq \liminf tr(y_n'')$: your assumption that leads to a contradiction is $tr(y)<\liminf tr(y_n'')$, or am I horribly mistaken? Also, I don't quite get the finite-rank-projection-step. When I try to do that, I only get $\geq 0$ for the last equation due to a $-\epsilon$ for the finite-rank convergence, $tr((y''_n-y)p) \in ]tr(y''_n-y)-\epsilon,tr(y''_n-y)+\epsilon[$.

Comment: You are right, that argument is completely wrong. I'm running out to teach now, so I'll erase it for now and I'll check it in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks! Your effort is appreciated. I will answer my own question if I find it out.

Comment: I made a new attempt. I hope it works!

Comment: Thanks, I understand! The pointwise sup of l.s.c. functions is l.s.c. My google fu also led me to Advanced Real Analysis by Knapp, Proposition 4.13.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/64737846/Advanced-Real-Analysis#page=140

Comment: Proof in Knapp uses uniform boundedness principle in a simple way. Is this argument actually related to yours? I know both the unif. bound. principle and the pointwise limit of l.s.c. functions, but not how/if they are related.

Comment: Yes, I think one can use more or less the same idea. You fix a finite rank projection $P$, and then you have $$\mbox{tr}(yP)=\lim\mbox{tr}(y_n'P)\leq\liminf\mbox{tr}(y_n').$$ Here we are using that $(y_n')^{1/2}P(y_n')^{1/2}\leq y_n'$ by the fact that $P$ is a projection and $y_n'\geq0$. The argument is completed by noting that $\mbox{tr}(y)=\sup\{\mbox{tr}(yP):\ \mbox{$P$ is a finite-rank projection}\}$. In the end, this  is not really that much simpler.